# Const correctness in automatic template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, c++17

In the following example I would expect the line `a.foo(j);` to pass the const qualifier to the templated method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T i) const
    {
        std::cout << "Is const type: " << std::is_const<T>::value << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {

    A a;

    int i = 0;
    const int j = 0;

    a.foo(i);
    a.foo(j);

    a.foo<decltype(i)>(i);
    a.foo<decltype(j)>(j);

    a.foo<int>(i);
    a.foo<const int>(j);

    return 0;
}
```

However the output I get both from gcc and clang (c++17) is the following.

```
Is const type: 0
Is const type: 0
Is const type: 0
Is const type: 1
Is const type: 0
Is const type: 1
```

The second row is false instead of true. So why automatic template deduction drops cv qualifiers? Is any specific reason why this happened?

PS. The example above can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/RG8HTW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deduction over the type `T` will always be decayed. The decayed type for `int const` is simply `int`. The decayed type of a `int[3]` is `int*`.

The thing is, this code *is* const correct.

Yes, inside `foo` you can't ever change the value of `j`. Inside `foo` you have a copy and it's up to `foo` to decide if it want its own parameters to be constant inside the function body or not.

However, there is other form of deductions that has to maintain the `const` to be callable with the arguments. This is not a solution for your code but simply an example:

```
template<typename T>
void frob(T& i)
{
    std::cout << "Will it be const? " << std::is_const<T>::value << "\n";
}

auto main() -> int {
    int const myInt = 9;
    frob(myInt);
}
```

To be called at all, the parameter must be `int const&` so it's what is going to be deduced.

Comment: Except this changes `foo(1)` from legal to illegal. I'd suggest a forwarding reference instead: `template <typename T> void foo(T&& i)`

Comment: Yes indeed with the initial approach I have a copy. Shouldn't the compiler be able to see that I do not change the i,j inside the foo function and decide the const accordingly? I mean that it is valid to have a `void foo(const int i)` function.

Comment: No. The const inside the main is orthogonal to the const inside the `foo` function. You could for example never change the value inside the main but mutate your copy inside `foo` as you please. It should not depend on the constness of object inside other scope.

Comment: OK I see! And how can I get always a const T inside the foo and forbid the mutation of i in every case? Defining `void foo(const T i) const` or `void foo(const T& i) const` also returns false.

Comment: Hoo well it is becasue I pass `is_const<T>` T to is_const nevermind! Thank you very much!